# How to sort prefix_100.png greater than prefix_2.png?

Tags: c#, .net

it might be some logic issue, but can't figure out

how can I sort my files where prefix_100.png is greater than prefix_2.png ?

thanks

```
        var filesRaw = Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.png").Select(fn => new FileInfo(fn)).
                                OrderBy(f => f.Name).ToList();
```

Comment: it may help if the filenames had leading zeros like `prefix_002.png`

Comment: Right justify the numeric portion: `prefix_002.png`. Either rename the files or extract the numeric portion and right-justify it while you're sorting.

Comment: [Padding msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/66f6d830(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Search term "natural sort" - make sure to check other answers (i.e. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/248603/natural-sort-order-in-c-sharp) if you find duplicate did not cover all possibilities.